# 1 Route en 2 Middleware me bloquea

Tags: laravel

Tengo 2 middleware para definir roles pero, al agregar un Route a a los 2, en uno se me bloquea.

Así lo definí:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['usuarioCalidad']],function(){

Route::resource('QualityCoreCutting/CC3/','QualityHojaInspeccionController');

});

Route::group(['middleware'=>['usuarioCalidad']],function(){

Route::resource('QualityCoreCutting/CC3/','QualityHojaInspeccionController');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me seguía bloqueando un usuario pero lo resolví de la sig. manera en el middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();
    if($usuario_actual->type!='Calidad' AND $usuario_actual->type!='Administrador'){
    //  return view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","No tiene suficientes Privilegios para acceder a esta seccion");
        return redirect('/denegado');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En el ejemplo que pones son iguales, pero si vas a poner la misma ruta en los 2 middlewares  mejor ponla separada(fuera de los groups) con los middlewares definidos en la ruta

```
Route::resource('QualityCoreCutting/CC3/','QualityHojaInspeccionController')
     ->middleware('usuarioCalidad', 'ejemploOtro');
```